# How to give ubuntu terminal commands from a program in GO language?

Tags: ubuntu, go

Is there any possibility to give ubuntu terminal commands,from a GO language program. 
(GO is installed in ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You use [the exec package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/). Check out the following examples:

- [Spawning Processes](https://gobyexample.com/spawning-processes)
- [Exec'ing Processes](https://gobyexample.com/execing-processes)

I'd include an example in my answer, but you've provided no information whatsoever on what it is you're trying to do, so instead I've linked to some helpful examples.